# Dynamic table with multiple datepickers

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a web form which has dynamic table using repeating rows. New rows are added by calling the addRow function below:

```
function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {


            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
            }
```

I would like one datepicker (or more) in each row. Datepicker from here:
http://www.frequency-decoder.com/2011/10/11/unobtrusive-accessible-datepicker-widgit-v6

I need the following script for each datepicker:

```
<script>
datePickerController.createDatePicker({ 
// Associate the text input to a DD/MM/YYYY date format                            
formElements:{"formInputName":"%Y-%m-%d"}
}); 
</script>
```

How can I easily execute this script for each table row that is added? I'm aware that using  in innerHTML does not work. Please see the attached image for the desired result.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHn2w.jpg]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is going to be very difficult (not impossible) for you to do .. because of the way you create your table - taking the innerHTML from your previous column and then creating a new row based on that one .... you really need to create unique IDs for each input that will use the datepicker - then you can just call the createDatePicker method - passing the forminputname of the new inputs you created ....

Comment: I'm aware of the necessity for unique IDs and names for each input. I will implement with arrays or a counter variable. I'm just providing a basic framework so that someone can help get me started. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create id's for each of the inputs you create and also use a class to show which input should use the date picker ...

Working demo here -> http://jsfiddle.net/S8Vky/3/

Example :

HTML

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td><input class="text" type="text" id="row-0-0" value=""/></td>
        <td><input class="cal" type="text" id="row-0-1" value=""/></td>
        <td><input class="cal" type="text" id="row-0-2" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="addRow('mytable')" value="Add Row"/>
```

JavaScript

```
function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        //alert(newcell.childNodes);
        switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
        case "text":
            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
            break;
        case "checkbox":
            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
            break;
        case "select-one":
            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
            break;
        }

        var newrowid = "row-" + rowCount + "-" + i;
        newcell.childNodes[0].id = newrowid;
        var obj = {};
        obj[newrowid] = "%d/%m/%Y";
        if (newcell.childNodes[0].className == 'cal') {
            datePickerController.createDatePicker({
                formElements: obj
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ManseUK, fantastic. This is exactly what I was looking for, to get me started. I'll have a go with this in mind. Your help and demo is really appreciated!

Comment: @Tezzums no probs ... not ideal but working none the less - carefull about copying the cell above because it copies everything ... even the already created datepicker ...

Comment: @Tezzums if i was doing this .. i would [create the elements from scratch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement) rather than copy a previous line - but thats just me :-)

Comment: That makes sense. As you've pointed out, I've noticed that everything will be copied from the first row, including the datepicker. I thought I could avoid this by using this code in the first row:

var table = document.getElementById("itemTable");

var rowCount = table.rows.length;


if(rowCount = 1) {

 datePickerController.createDatePicker({
 
 formElements:{"date-0-1":"%Y-%m-%d"}
});

However, I noticed that rowCount doesn't update when I add a row. I would prefer to have the first row created when I load the page. Any suggestions? Can't thank you enough for your time!

Comment: ManseUK I add elements using arrays in name, insted of changing the ids. For example: //licenseDate
    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
    element = document.createElement("input");
    element.type = "text";
    element.name = "licenseDate[]";
    element.size = columnSize;
    cell7.appendChild(element); Now I want to change this element to become datepicker instead of plain text. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a prefix or suffix like _date on your field name. Then just loop on it when assigning the datepicker. Something like this:

```
$("input[id$='_date']").each(function(){
  $(this).datepicker();
});
```